# Forcing y-axis to 0 when using chained transitions

Tags: d3.js, transition

I'm new to D3 and working on a modified version of Chained Transitions: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3903818.

However one problem I'm running into is forcing the y-axis to start at 0. Normally this would be simple fix with changing the y domain and range properties when declaring your other variables but in the context of the transition function, I'm running into issues. Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/maureenlinke/DCc6g/

I believe the issue is here:

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

```
y.domain([
  d3.min(homes, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.price; }); }),
  d3.max(homes, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.price; }); })
  ]);
```

Thanks,

Maureen

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the domain:

```
var maxPrice = d3.max(homes, function(c) { 
    return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.price; }); 
});
y.domain([0, maxPrice]);
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the first axis but not the second. When it transitions to the second axis it does not begin at zero. I believe there's something that should be added here.    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[sale]; }));
      var t1 = t0.transition();
      t1.selectAll(".line").attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });
      t1.selectAll(".label").attr("transform", transform);
      t1.selectAll(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

Comment: The problem is the use of extent. d3.extent will return an array with the minimum and the maximum value of the arguments (the data array and the accesor function). Just replace the minimum with 0 in the second axis as well.

Comment: I've tried y.domain(0,maxPrice) function(d) { return d[sale]; })); which doesn't work.

Comment: or  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

    var maxPrice = d3.max(homes, function(c) { 
    return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.price; }); 
    });

    y.domain([0,maxPrice]);
    y.domain([0,maxPrice]);

Answer (score 0):

The d3.extent function returns the min/max range of the data in the form of an array [min, max].

Normally, you would code the following:

```
y.domain( d3.extent(homes, function(d) { return d.price; }) );
```

So the following should work:

```
var yRange = d3.extent(homes, function(d) { return d.price; });
y.domain( [0, yRange[1] ); // Force the min to 0
```